# jersey : How to send Data from Servlet to Jersey Filter

Tags: rest, jersey

Inside a  servlet doPost method i am setting some data inside the MultivaluedMap  as shown .

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
            System.out.println("Session ID For Servlet"+sess.getId());

            sess.setAttribute("Name","ID");

            MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
              formData.add("name1", "val1");
              formData.add("name2", "val2");

            response.sendRedirect("ajax/balances");
    }
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i get that value inside jersey Filter

This is my Filter

```
public class MineFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
        @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {

            return request ;
        }
```

Or is there any better way if one can send data from Servlet to  Jersey Filter ??

Answer (score 0):

In Jersey there are two types of interfaces `ContainerRequstFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` and both of these have one method `void filter(conextInfo)` so in a filter if we implement only `ContainerRequestFilter` it will only be invoked before the request reaches the servlet and so these are sometimes also called request filters. Now if we want to intercept a response we need to write a class which implements both of these interfaces.

One obvious reason for this is that when the request in coming in for the first time there is no need of responseContext as we will be hardly using it so we can omit it by simply implementing the `ContainerRequestContext`. Now when we are talking about intercepting responses then we can clearly see the need for RequestContext which can be used to get information regarding the request. So for that purpose this is what we have. So a so called response filter will have the capability of filtering the request and response both. So when we override the void filter(context infos) of ContainerResponseFilter it has both request context and reponse context. The request context here will be in read only mode.

So once the request is past the servlet you can always intercept the response with an implementation of `ContainerResponseFilter` and fetch the value from the response.

```
@Provider
@Priority(2)        //set the priority just to make sure it is executed after the request filter
public class CustomResponseFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter{
 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCOntext) throws IOException {
     //dont Do anything here as this filter is intended for response processing 
 }

 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                    ContainerResponseContex responseContext) throws IOException {
     //work with the responseContext and let the requst pass through
 }

}
```